# how to get the promise value of return promise

Tags: reactjs, promise

Hi guys I'm new to Reactjs and I'm using Atom . I want to know if there's a way to  get the PromiseValue in return promise

[image: PromiseValue]

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your value will be in `then`(as result) or `catch`(as err):

```
promise.then(result => console.log(result)).catch( err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: thanks bro. it correct